How could I share files from my Raspberry Pi to my Laptop?
I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B which uses 32 bit Bookworm and have connected it to my network router (a BT hub) via ethernet cable.
I want to be able to read and write to all files on the Raspberry Pi from my Windows 11 laptop using the path \\192.168.1.123\example.
Currently, my PC can read a couple of files that I set up using Samba from that file directory but I can't see any of the original files not created using Samba or any of the USB Drives connected.
How could I make my laptop able to write and read to all the files and drives attached to the Raspberry Pi?
I also want any drives I attached to automatically be accessible by laptop so I don't have to change anything on my Raspberry Pi every time I attach a new drive.

Do I understand correctly that you've generally correctly set up Samba on the Raspberry Pi, and that the question is how to share USB drives and generally, other directories via Samba?

By the way, if you don't insist on being able to access things from Windows using \\Host\shared_directory (the leading double backslash is important, by the way!), and you can log in via SSH anyways, WinSCP has been the go-to SFTP/SCP client for decades :)

"How could I make my laptop able to write and read to all the files and drives attached to the Raspberry Pi" - this is a really really bad idea. Unless you don't actually mean "all".

@ChrisDavies I meant all, if there is a way to only share the external drives that that would be preferable but I'm not massively worried about the security of my Pi as I can just wipe the SD card and re-install the OS if anything goes wrong.

@MarcusMüller I don't mind whether I use Samba. Would the method you suggested allow me to map the network location to a drive letter and if I added a new USB stick or HDD drive to the Raspberry Pi, would I have to do anything on the Raspberry Pi to make it accessible from my Laptop?

@JacobBoughton problem with access to "all" via drive letter mapping is that the file properties on a Linux box simply don't map directly to what can be handled on windows, so write access is a really bad idea from front to back; I won't help you break your Raspberry PI minutes after you spent hours getting the bad idea to run. That being said, you could definitely add a udev rule that automatically mounts every newly attached USB drive, then adds it as samba share, and then have a script that you can run to let the reverse happen when you want to remove the drive.

For exploring and working with all files on the Raspberry Pi, WinSCP is the way to go (it would have taken you less time to install it than to ask about it, and it does come with extensive documentation, which I linked to).

@MarcusMüller Thanks for your help, if you want to write your comments as an answer, once I get home and have tested your suggestion, I'll accept it.

In general, I think the suggestion to use WinSCP is a good one...  but as I've not used Windows in many years, you should read the WinSCP Intro, and decide that for yourself.
WRT Samba, I think the key to doing what you want is in the /etc/smb.conf file on your Raspberry Pi. Open this file with your editor (I'll assume nano here), and go to the section named #===== Share Definitions ====; or perhaps it's just marked as [homes]. In any case, you're safe going to the end of the smb.conf file.
Add a "configuration block" for each share you want to add. For example, to add a USB drive, add a "configuration block" we'll call [usbshare]:
$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

#... editor opens file; add the following lines: 

[usbshare]
path = /mnt/myusbstick
read only = no
public = yes
writable = yes

#... save the file, and close the editor

$ 

To add all the files from your Raspberry Pi's home directory, edit (or add) the following in your /etc/smb.conf file:
$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

#... editor opens file; add/edit the following lines: 

[homes]
browseable = yes
read only = no

#... save the file, and close the editor

$ 

To add all the files from your Raspberry Pi, do this:
$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

#... editor opens file; add the following lines: 

[root$]
path = /
create mask = 0755
force user = root
browsable = yes

#... save the file, and close the editor

$ sudo smbpasswd -a root

New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Added user root.

$

NOTE: Be careful with this one (above); esp editing Linux files in a Windows text editor (i.e. don't do it unless you know what you're doing).
Before the samba server on your RPi can access the USB drive, the drive will have to be mounted (homes and root$ are already mounted) on your RPi. I generally prefer to set up all of my mounts in the file /etc/fstab, so we'll illustrate that here:
First, plug the USB drive into the RPi. Then, from the terminal on the RPi, let's use lsblk to get the information we need to create the appropriate entry in /etc/fstab:
$ lsblk --fs

NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1      exfat  1.0   SANDISK16GB 5B00-9E5C
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   FAT32 bootfs      DDE5-BCDC                             203.1M    20% /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   1.0   rootfs      f877e440-e1dc-41e3-8cc0-62640c857595   48.7G    12% /

The USB drive is at sda1. Note the entries for FSTYPE, LABEL, and UUID; i.e. exfat, SANDISK16GB and 5B00-9E5C, respectively. Your USB may be FAT32 aka vfat, ext<X> or some Windows-peculiar filesystem.
Next, we'll add this USB drive to /etc/fstab, using our nano editor (again):
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab

#... editor opens file; add the following line: 

LABEL=SANDISK16GB /mnt/myusbstick exfat rw,nofail,user 0 0

#... save the file, and close the editor

$

Next, create the mount point in the Rpi filesystem:
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/myusbstick   # from the smb.conf configuration for [usbshare]

Next, actually mount the USB drive:
$ sudo mount -a
$

Assuming all that went OK, your USB drive should now be mounted on your RPi, and the Samba server should allow you to access it from Windows. (sorry - but I don't know how this access is done in Windows :/  )  HOWEVER, the share name will be usbshare. Possibly something like //raspberrypi/usbshare ??
In addition you have shares named homes and root$ that allow you access to your user's directory (/home/pi, or whatever user), and to your / (root) file system folder. If you opted to add all 3 shares (usbshare, homes and root$), you should now be able to access any or all of them.
In closing:
By necessity I've omitted some (numerous actually) details that may be important to your situation. Feel free to add a comment and edit your Question to add those details & I'll try to address them.
Note that the Samba documentation is both wide and deep! Again, I'm not a Windows user in many years, but you may find it simpler to rely upon WinSCP
